# Border around div; Background color not filling in completely

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a border around a `div` and I am unable to do so effectively.

Main Issues:

- The middle line that separates the border into two sections will not extend the entire length of the border.
- The background color (`.insiderbox` class) for the top section is out of alignment.
- I want the border to hug the div in a leaner fashion.

```css
.Box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 26px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  width: 325px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  /* or whatever */
  padding: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 0 0 0px;
}
.insiderBox {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<div id="ValidationPanel" Visible="false" runat="server" class="Box">
  <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height: 79px; width: 326px;" class="insiderBox">
    <h3 style="margin-bottom:20px; width: 319px;">
      Enter ATM Cash-In Ticket Amount
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtValidateTotals" runat="server" length="50" title="Please Enter Totals Here" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnValidationPanelValidateTotals" Text="Validate Totals" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnValidationPanelValidateTotals_Click" width="200" />
    asdasdasdasdasd
  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qade21v1/1/)

Comment: For starters .Box should have padding:0

Comment: Not JavaScript, Please remove tag.

Comment: Hello thanks for your time. padding:0; didn't change anything however.

Comment: There is no javascript? only asp.

Comment: Someone edited my answer and removed code. Please see fiddle for more accurate code representation.

Comment: @Indianaadminstopstuck If you look at the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26149792/revisions), you will see nobody has removed your code. The problem was that you didn't format well your html as code, so it was partially parsed as html.

Comment: @Oriol d'oh gotcha. sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.Box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 26px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  width: 325px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  /* or whatever */
  padding: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 0 0 0px;
}
.insiderBox {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="ValidationPanel" Visible="false" runat="server" class="Box">
  <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height: 79px;" class="insiderBox">
    <h3 style="margin-bottom:20px; width: 319px;">
      Enter ATM Cash-In Ticket Amount
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtValidateTotals" runat="server" length="50" title="Please Enter Totals Here" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnValidationPanelValidateTotals" Text="Validate Totals" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnValidationPanelValidateTotals_Click" width="200" />
    asdasdasdasdasd
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you change, and why?

Comment: Thanks for your help! But there is still a white line between the text and the top of the border.

Comment: Set .Box to padding 0, set h3 to margin:0, remove the inline css width on .insidebox

Answer (score 0):

Your .Box div has padding around it, remove the padding and you will get your desired result.

```
.Box {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Another thing would be to set the background on the div with the border, instead of the div inside. This is probably a better option.

```
.Box {
  background: #E2E2E2;
}
```

Comment: How is it not the correct solution? It fixed the padding issue for me.

Comment: @FunkDoc This is a valid answer and hopefully you did not downvote this. The OP is unclear on 2 of their 3 objectives. Once clarified, GSaunders can update their answer.

Comment: GSaunders assisted with my solution with his first answer. There's a whole lot of downvoting around here for nooooo reason.